# Learning jQuery: if & else statements, is this valid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

At the moment I'm learning jQuery and I hit the topic about if/else statements. As I have no background in programming this topic is something that I need to practice a bit more to get a thorough understanding of it.

The book I'm studying gave me the advice of just writing different blocks of if/else statements. I just had an idea and wanted to know if its valid:

```
$(morningWakeup).ready(function() {
    $('#arms').reaction(function() {
    if($'#kid').is(':nagging')) {
        $('#kid').slap();
    } else {
        $('#kid').hug();
    }
 });
});
```

Let me make it clear that this is a joke of course, but I want to know if this is valid code and if you can supply me with some more examples? Thank you!

Comment: It's also a good idea to familiarise yoursefl with standard javascript conventions as well:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Best of luck with learning javascript :)

Comment: @elduderino: Thanks, I will certainly take a look at W3C :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic form is perfectly fine, though you've misplaced some parentheses on this line: `if($'#kid').is(':nagging')) {`. It should be `if ($('#kid').is(':nagging')) {` instead. Also, note that you'll have better luck setting `$('#kid').attr('behaving')` to `true` if you just `ignore()` him/her for a while instead of `slap()`ing them. Negative reinforcement sucks. :)

Comment: Ah yes I missed an ( at the beginning, thanks for pointing that out. And also much gratitude on the negative reinforcement ;)

Comment: Haha, no problem. Also, @Pekka's advice is very good: you'll learn a lot about JavaScript and jQuery just by practicing on some real HTML.

Comment: The book I'm reading right now is from Sitepoint: Learning jQuery: From Novice to Ninja and its filled with real HTML examples. So I'm good there and when I'm trough with the book I have many ideas of using jQuery :)

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing up Javascript and jQuery here: The `if/else` is basically valid, but the jQuery part (`.is` etc.) will strongly depend on whether the DOM elements exist, whether they have that property etc.

I would recommend starting with real live HTML to go along.

That, and of course the syntax error @bcat points out...

Comment: I was under the impression that jquery is javascript.

Comment: @Ash yup, that's my point: if/else constructs are JavaScript; `$()` and `.is()` and the plethora of helper functions are jQuery.

Comment: Of course my example can only be fired if the DOM elements exist (and there is a property attached), thanks for pointing that out. My brain came up with this example in a split second. It does that often to get an understanding of things, but you are right when it comes to live HTML. It would make more sense in a practical way.

Comment: So `$()` and `.is()` are jQuery specific?

Comment: @Wollen yes, `$()` is a helper function defined by jQuery (an alias to `jQuery()`) and `.is()` is a method of a DOM element extended by jQuery.

Comment: I read about the `$()` which is an alias to `jQuery()`, but this is only for jQuery and not for other JS library's?

Comment: @Wollen other libraries like Prototype also use `$` as a shortcut to *their* DOM extension functions. Which is one of the reasons they are not easy to make work together on one page.

Comment: So say for example that one would like to use 2 different JS library's on one page (site), they can't use the `$`? Or for one library the `$` and the other the regular alias?

Comment: @Wollen usually the latter:  that's the way jQuery's compatibility plugin works.